# python csv read row but index out of range

Tags: python, csv

This is my code:

```
with open('example.csv','r',encoding='utf8') as agr:

    agr_csv = csv.reader(agr, delimiter=',')
    for line in agr_csv:
        name = line[0]
        year = line[2:3]
        countryname[name].append(year)
```

but I always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "quiz_4.py", line 72, in <module>
name = line[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What is the cause?

Comment: maybe there are empty lines in your CSV

Comment: Try to `print(line)` in you for loop, and write the output

Answer (score 1):

Your code will fail if there are empty lines. You could however simply skip them:

```
with open('example.csv','r',encoding='utf8') as agr:
    agr_csv = csv.reader(agr, delimiter=',')
    for line in agr_csv:
        print("Line: >{}<".format(line)) # for debugging
        if(not line): # check if the line is empty
            continue  # skip
        name = line[0]
        year = line[2:3]
        countryname[name].append(year)
```